# php работа с текстом

Tags: php

Те кто шарят помогите пожалуйста...

```
$text =".......
<tr>
<td width="80" align="center">12345</td>
<td width="80" align="center">today</td>
<td width="200">delete</td>
</tr>
.......";
```

Вот дана переменная $text (я написал только необходимый код, раньше него и после него так-же идут строки) вот нужно определить если `<td width="200">delete</td>` при условии что `<td width="80" align="center">today</td>` то `12345` - записать в переменную, и так пробежаться по всему $text (он весь состоит из этой таблицы)

Comment: ниче не понятно!!!

Comment: вроде все доступно :<

Comment: Что нужно определить, при каком условии и что вообще должно произойти?

Comment: Если честно, то ничего не понятно из задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я перефразирую:

Есть таблица из строк

12345 today delete

12345 today delete

12345 today delete

12345 today delete

12345 today delete

Нужно пройтись по всей таблице и каждую 12345 добавить в массив $result, если след. за ней today и delete.

Comment: Только я убегаю, поэтому составляйте регулярки сами:)

Comment: если у вас есть проблема и вы решили решать её с помощью регулярок, то у вас 2 проблемы ))))

Comment: @kemerov4anin а что не так с регулярными выражениями ? Для парсинга текста - это то что доктор прописал.